# how can i get the right datetime info to the user registered date in django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-3.x

i create a website using django .and now i want show the number of  users registered today,
so i write this code

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
  um=get_user_model()
  now=timezone.now()
    todayusers=um.objects.filter(date_joined__day=now.day,date_joined__month=now.month,date_joined__year=now.year).count()
```

today it is 4th july 2014 ,and i find today mywebsite get two users registered

but it show todayusers =0
i do not knwo why ?
 so i change the code to make it simple

```
todayusers=um.objects.filter(date_joined__day=4).count()
```

it show todayusers=0
and i change it to

```
todayusers=um.objects.filter(date_joined__day=3).count()
```

ok ,this time ,it show todayusers=2

i find one of the user ,its user id is 13,so i get that user

```
u13=um.objects.get(ud=13)
```

now i check its date_joined ,this datetime filed

```
u13.date_joined.day=4
```

that means ,it should be 4th july ,why when i query it in django ,it can not find

my django `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'`

any one can help me

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
todayusers=um.objects.filter(date__year='2014', 
        date__month='07', date__day='04').count()
```

OR

```
start_date = datetime.date(2014, 7, 4)
end_date = datetime.date(2014, 7, 4)
todayusers = um.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date)).count()
```

OR

```
todayusers = um.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.datetime.today()).count()
```

OR

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

asia_sh = timezone("Asia/Shanghai")

startdate = datetime(2014, 07, 04, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=asia_sh)
enddate = datetime(2014, 07, 04, 23, 59, 59, tzinfo=aisa_sh)


todayusers = um.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date)).count()
```

Comment: no ,it do not work,the problem is ,it always treat the day =3 not today day should be 4

Comment: @zzlettle Try  um.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.datetime.today()).count()

Comment: it show DateTimeField MyUser.date_joined received a naive datetime (2014-07-04 19:47:47.225044) while time zone support is active.

Comment: Sorry @zzlettle I don't have env to test the exact output, please see if the last solution I just edited.

Comment: this is what i do ,but still not work. from django.utils import timezone   now=timezone.now().replace(hour=8,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)   todayusers=um.objects.filter(date_joined__gte=now).count()  still todayuser=0

Comment: can you see what sql query is generated `m.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.datetime.today()).count().query`

Comment: ok this time it work ,this is the code   day=timezone.now().day-1    now=timezone.now().replace(day=day,hour=8,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)    todayusers=um.objects.filter(date_joined__gte=now).count()  now todayusers=2 done .thanks Aedill

Comment: at last i think this is the better way   tz==pytz.timezone("Asia/Shanghai")   today=datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0,tzinfo=china) 
 todayusers=um.objects.filter(date_joined__gte=today).count()